# Incorrect data fetching by EclipseLink

Tags: java, mysql, sql, orm, eclipselink

in my java BackEnd I'm using EclipseLink as ORM. everything was fine till yesterday. when I want to get data from db, ORM's query fetch only 1 row from mysql db, but while debugging I get the generated sql string and run it in MySQL Workbench and I get 200+ rows (correct number). I don't understand why in code query not working as expected. this is my orm's query:

```
String queryString = "select c from Contract c " +
                    "join c.contractForms cf " +
                    "join c.insuredPerson per " +
                    "join c.paymentGraphs pg " +
                    "join c.payments pm " +
                    "join cf.company com " +
                    "join cf.curator cur " +
                    "join cf.insuranceType insType " +
                    "where c.state = :state " +
                    "and cf.state = :state and pg.state = :state and pm.state = :state ";
Query query= em.createQuery(queryString).setParameter("state", "A");
```

This one is generated sql String:

```
SELECT *
FROM Contract t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN ContractForm t2 ON (t2.CONTRACT_ID = t1.ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PaymentGraph t4 ON (t4.CONTRACT_ID = t1.ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Payment t5 ON (t5.CONTRACT_ID = t1.ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Claim t0 ON (t0.CONTRACT_ID = t1.ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN OfferForm t3 ON (t3.CONTRACT_ID = t1.ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ReinsuranceForm t6 ON (t6.CONTRACT_ID = t1.ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ReinsuranceOfferForm t7 ON (t7.CONTRACT_ID = t1.ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ReinsurerData t8 ON (t8.CONTRACT_ID = t1.ID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Workflow t9 ON (t9.CONTRACT_ID = t1.ID)
  , ReferenceData t11, InsuredPerson t10, ReferenceData t13, ReferenceData t12
WHERE (((((t1.STATE = 'A') AND (t2.STATE = 'A')) AND (t4.STATE = 'A')) AND (t5.STATE = 'A')) AND
       ((((t10.ID = t1.PERSON_ID) AND (t11.ID = t2.CONTRACT_COMPANY_ID)) AND (t12.ID = t2.CURATOR_ID)) AND
        (t13.ID = t2.INSURANCE_TYPE)))
ORDER BY t2.CONTRACT_DATE DESC
```

I can't find any solution for this problem. can anybody say what is the problem and how I can solve it?

Comment: How many distinct `Contract` does the sql query return ?

Comment: @FlorentBayle 115

Comment: The SQL shown doesn't match the JPQL. The SQL is using left joins, while the JPQL is just using 'join' which is an inner join that filters out nulls. They are not the same query.  You will want to use 'left join' in your JPQL to get similar results.

Comment: @Chris but I get this SQL query from debug windows while debuging the app from Query parameter. How it can be wrong?

Comment: Try turning EclipseLink logging to finest to get the SQL it will use in the DB. EclipseLink shouldn't be putting the parameter in the SQL so it can use a prepared statement for the query, so I can't say where this SQL is coming from.